# Getting an error "org.apache.jasper.el.JspMethodNotFoundException"

Tags: java, jsf-2, web

I am getting the following error in my Web application. I have been working on JSF for quite a while now but I can't find a solution to this error.

```
Nov 27, 2013 11:00:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke 
SEVERE: servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
org.apache.jasper.el.JspMethodNotFoundException: /CustomerPFM.jsp(70,2) '#customerPfmBean.MakeConnections}' Method not found: bean.CustomerPfmBean@1900abac.MakeConnections()
```

This is my JSP

**CustomerPFM.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="f"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="h"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Allocate PM Success</title>
</head>
<body>
<f:view>
<h:form>
<h3> Customers</h3>
    <h:dataTable border="1" value="#{customerPfmBean.customerDetails}" var="cust">
        <h:column id="column1">
        <h:outputText value="#{cust.id}"></h:outputText>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Customer ID"></h:outputText>
            </f:facet>
        </h:column>
        <h:column id="column2">
        <h:outputText value="#{cust.customerName }"></h:outputText>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Customer Name"></h:outputText>
            </f:facet>
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>

    <h3>Portfolio Managers</h3>

    <h:dataTable border="1" value="#{customerPfmBean.pfmDetails}" var="pfm">
        <h:column id="column1">
        <h:outputText value="#{pfm.id}"></h:outputText>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Portfolio Manager ID"></h:outputText>
            </f:facet>
        </h:column>
        <h:column id="column2">
        <h:outputText value="#{pfm.pfmName}"></h:outputText>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Portfolio Manager Name"></h:outputText>
            </f:facet>
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>

    <h3>Active Portfolio Managers Allocations</h3>
    <h:dataTable border="1" value="#{customerPfmBean.customerPfms }" var="cp">
        <h:column id="column1">
        <h:outputText value="#{cp.id.pfmUser}"></h:outputText>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="PortFolio Manager ID"></h:outputText>
            </f:facet>
        </h:column>
        <h:column id="column2">
        <h:outputText value="#{cp.id.custUser}"></h:outputText>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Customer ID"></h:outputText>
            </f:facet>
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>

    <h:panelGrid columns="3">
    <h:outputText value="Enter the Customer Id"></h:outputText>
    <h:inputText value="#{customerPfmBean.custId}" id="custId" required="true" requiredMessage="*Cant be left blank"></h:inputText>
    <h:message for="custId" style="color: #FF0000"></h:message>
    <h:outputText value="Enter the Portfolio Manager Id"></h:outputText>
    <h:inputText value="#{customerPfmBean.pmId}" id="pmId" required="true" requiredMessage="*Cant be left blank"></h:inputText>
    <h:message for="pmId" style="color: #FF0000"></h:message>

    <h:commandButton value="Connect Customer to PM" type="submit" action="#{customerPfmBean.MakeConnections}"></h:commandButton>
    <h:commandButton value="Reset" type="reset"></h:commandButton></h:panelGrid><br><br>
    <h:outputText value="#{customerPfmBean.message}" style="color: #FF0000"></h:outputText><br>
    <h:outputLink value="AdminWelcomePage.jsp">Home</h:outputLink><br>

<h:commandLink action="#{logout.logout}">LogOut</h:commandLink>
</h:form>

</f:view>
</body>
</html>
```

My Managed Bean
**CustomerPFM.java**

```
package bean;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import service.CustomerPFMService;
import service.CustomerService;
import service.PMService;
import model.CustomerDetail;
import model.CustomerPfm;
import model.PfmDetail;


public class CustomerPfmBean {
private String custId;
private String pmId;
private List<PfmDetail> pfmDetails;
private List<CustomerDetail> customerDetails;
private List<CustomerPfm> customerPfms;
private String message;
public String getCustId() {
    return custId;
}
public void setCustId(String custId) {
    this.custId = custId;
}
public String getPmId() {
    return pmId;
}
public void setPmId(String pmId) {
    this.pmId = pmId;
}
public List<PfmDetail> getPfmDetails() {
    return pfmDetails;
}
public void setPfmDetails(List<PfmDetail> pfmDetails) {
    this.pfmDetails = pfmDetails;
}
public List<CustomerDetail> getCustomerDetails() {
    return customerDetails;
}
public void setCustomerDetails(List<CustomerDetail> customerDetails) {
    this.customerDetails = customerDetails;
}
public List<CustomerPfm> getCustomerPfms() {
    return customerPfms;
}
public void setCustomerPfms(List<CustomerPfm> customerPfms) {
    this.customerPfms = customerPfms;
}

public String getAllCustPM()
{
    this.customerDetails=new ArrayList<CustomerDetail>();
    this.pfmDetails=new ArrayList<PfmDetail>();
    this.customerPfms=new ArrayList<CustomerPfm>();
    this.customerDetails=new CustomerService().getAllCustomer();
    this.pfmDetails = new PMService().getAllPM();
    if((customerDetails.size()==0) || pfmDetails.size()==0)
    {
        return "cust-pm-fail";
    }
    else 
    {
        this.customerPfms=new CustomerPFMService().getALLCustomerandPFM();
        return "cust-pm-success";
    }
}

public String MakeConnections()
{
    int cid= Integer.parseInt(this.custId);
    int pid= Integer.parseInt(this.pmId);
    CustomerPFMService service= new CustomerPFMService();
    String saveMessage= service.save(cid, pid);
    if(saveMessage.equals("cust-fail"))
    {
        this.message="Customer does not exist";
        return "cust-fail";
    }
    else if (saveMessage.equals("pm-fail"))
    {
        this.message="PM does not exist";
        return "pm-fail";
    }
    else if (saveMessage.equals("pm-exist-fail"))
    {
        this.message="Already allocated customer to PM";
        return "pm-exist-fail";
    }
    else 
    {
        this.message="";
        this.custId="";
        this.pmId="";
        return "success";
    }
}



public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}
public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}
```

}

My faces.config file

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>customerPfmBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>bean.CustomerPfmBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>

<navigation-rule>
    <display-name>CustomerPFM</display-name>
    <from-view-id>/CustomerPFM.jsp</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>cust-fail</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/CustomerPFM.jsp</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
<navigation-rule>
    <display-name>CustomerPFM</display-name>
    <from-view-id>/CustomerPFM.jsp</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>pm-fail</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/CustomerPFM.jsp</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
<navigation-rule>
    <display-name>CustomerPFM</display-name>
    <from-view-id>/CustomerPFM.jsp</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>pm-exist-fail</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/CustomerPFM.jsp</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
<navigation-rule>
    <display-name>CustomerPFM</display-name>
    <from-view-id>/CustomerPFM.jsp</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/CustomerPFMSucess.jsp</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

No idea what is happening? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: it says it does not find a method. which line is throwing the error?

Comment: <h:commandButton value="Connect Customer to PM" type="submit" action="#{customerPfmBean.MakeConnections}"></h:commandButton> this line is giving error. It says not able to find method MakeConnections method in Managed Bean class. but the function is there, there is no signature mistake or spelling mistake in the function.

Comment: I don't know what has happening.... I just took the war file of the project, created a new workspace imported the war file ran the project .... and its working. This was wierd and almost wasted 24 hrs :(

Comment: better write it in the answer section and accept it as a correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what was happening.... I just took the war file of the project, created a new workspace imported the war file ran the project .... and its working.